# R: Parallel execution nested within a sequential loop with dependency

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Let's say I have two functions `f1` and `f2`. `f2` is designed to take the output of `f1` as an argument, and `f1` is designed to take its own output to update it. Before the loop starts, output from `f1` is initialized. Then within each iteration, `f2` takes the previous output from `f1` and executes, then `f1` executes to update its own output. Two vectors will gather the sequential output from `f1` and `f2` respectively. The following code is a simple working example:

```
f1 <- function(x) return(x + pi)
f2 <- function(x) return(log(x))

f1.result <- res1 <- f1(1)
f2.result <- NULL

for(i in 2:100) { ## Need to parallelize these two lines ##
  res2 <- f2(res1); f2.result <- c(f2.result, res2)
  res1 <- f1(res1); f1.result <- c(f1.result, res1)
}
```

I am looking to parallelize the two executions inside the loop i.e. to get them run at the same time. How do I achieve this in R? I am familiar with the basics of `foreach` but can't figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result in this example? Because I don't understand what `res2 <- f2(res1)` is doing inside the loop. Couldn't you just do `log(1 + (1:100) * pi)`, which would be much faster? Anyhow, how slow are these functions? Because parallelizing these two tasks only makes sense if they are very time-intensive.

Comment: @Roland This is just a simplified example to show the issue at hand. The example does not necessarily make any practical sense other than a demonstration of the problem. The actual functions I need to parallelize are indeed very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured this out. It's actually pretty simple. I use the `doParallel` package:

```
f1 <- function(x) return(x + pi)
f2 <- function(x) return(log(x))

f1.result <- res1 <- f1(1)
f2.result <- NULL

library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()

for(j in 2:100) {
  res <- foreach(i = 1:2, .combine = c) %dopar% {
    if(i==1) res <- f1(res1)
    else res <- f2(res1)
  }
  res1 <- res[1]; f1.result <- c(f1.result, res1)
  res2 <- res[2]; f2.result <- c(f2.result, res2)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```